# How to get the value of Azure App Configuration Feature Flag with specific label from Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-app-configuration, azure-feature-manager

I started using Azure App Configuration service and Feature Flags functionality in my project. I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-spring-boot) and was able to create a Spring boot project. I also created a FeatureFlagService class and autowired the FeatureManager class in it as shown below :

```
@Service
public class FeatureFlagService {

  private FeatureManager featureManager;

  public FeatureFlagService(FeatureManager featureManager) {
     this.featureManager = featureManager;
  }

  public boolean isFeatureEnabled() {
     return featureManager.isEnabledAsync("scopeid/MyFeature").block();
  }

}
```

With this I get the value of the feature flag 'MyFeature' but with no label.
I have the same feature defined with different labels in Azure App Configuration as shown below.

[image]

I need to fetch the feature flag with specific label. How can I achieve it at runtime?
I don't see a way to do it using the FeatureManager class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They only way to load from a label is by using `spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].feature-flags.label-filter`, the Feature Management Library itself has no concept of a label.

Comment: Hi @mrm9084, I intend to get the labels at run time. The property `spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].feature-flags.label-filter` goes in bootstrap.properties files. I found that if I use a low level dependency `azure-data-appconfiguration`, I can potentially fetch all the features with a specific label at run time. Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/data-appconfiguration-readme?view=azure-java-stable. The disadvantage of using this is to give up the Spring boot features.

Comment: Azure App Configuration Labels map to Spring profiles. You may be able to find something to help here https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/docs/azure-app-configuration/index.html, it is the complete documentation for both Spring libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I got `FeatureManager` to pull in non-blank labels with the following configuration path:

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].feature-flags.selects[0].label-filter
```

The key is that the other answer was missing the `selects` piece.

Here it is in yaml form:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      appconfiguration:
        enabled: true
        stores[0]:
          connection-string: ${APP_CONFIGURATION_CONNECTION_STRING}
          feature-flags:
            enabled: true
            selects[0]:
              # this pulls in flags with "local" label and no label (trailing comma)
              label-filter: local,
              # you can put key-filter here, too
```

Relevant source code:

- [com.azure.spring.cloud.appconfiguration.config.implementation.properties.FeatureFlagKeyValueSelector](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/spring/spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/cloud/appconfiguration/config/implementation/properties/FeatureFlagKeyValueSelector.java)
- [com.azure.spring.cloud.appconfiguration.config.implementation.AppConfigurationPropertySourceLocator#create](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/a9eff454e4e193affcd814e26cd252649a0db3de/sdk/spring/spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/cloud/appconfiguration/config/implementation/AppConfigurationPropertySourceLocator.java#L254)

Artifact:

```
artifactId=spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config
groupId=com.azure.spring
version=5.8.0
```

If you notice in the code, you can also use active Spring profiles for filtering the Azure feature flags by label.

You may want to to wire in a `AppConfigurationRefresh` bean to refresh feature flag values on demand. I think the refresh default is 5 minutes. You can setup a Spring scheduled task to invoke it more frequently. Or if you can find a way to override the default, feel free to share it here.